# Dynamically Expand Arraytype() Columns in Structured Streaming PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dynamic, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I have the following DataFrame:

```
root
 |-- sents: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
 |-- metadata: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: float (containsNull = true)

+----------+---------------------+
|sents     |metadata             |
+----------+---------------------+
|[1, -1, 0]|[0.4991, 0.5378, 0.0]|
|[-1]      |[0.6281]             |
|[-1]      |[0.463]              |
+----------+---------------------+
```

I want to expand each array item to its own column DYNAMICALLY so that it may look as follows:

```
+--------+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|sents[0]|sents[1]|sents[2]|metadata[0]|metadata[1]|metadata[2]|
+--------+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|       1|      -1|       0|     0.4991|     0.5378|        0.0|
|      -1|    null|    null|     0.6281|       null|       null|
|      -1|    null|    null|      0.463|       null|       null|
+--------+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

but in structured Streaming there are many limitations as to doing things dynamically:

I tried the following:

```
numcol = df.withColumn('phrasesNum', F.size('sents')).agg(F.max('phrasesNum')).head()
df = df.select(*[F.col('sents')[i] for i in range(numcol[0])],*[F.col('metadata')[i] for i in range(numcol[0])])
```

Also:

```
df_sizes = df.select(F.size('sents').alias('sents'))
df_max = df_sizes.agg(F.max('sents'))
nb_columns = df_max.collect()[0][0]

d = c.select(*[F.map_values(c['metadata'][i]).getItem(0).alias('confidenceIntervals'+"{}".format(j)).cast(DoubleType()) for i,j in enumerate(range(F.size('sents')))],
             *[c['sents'][i].alias('phraseSents'+"{}".format(j)).cast(IntegerType()) for i,j in enumerate(range(nb_columns))])
```

but I cannot use things like .head(), .collect(), or .take() in Structured Streaming to create the numeric variable that indicate the number of columns to dynamically create. Any ideas??

thanks to all

Comment: Do you know the maximum length of the array? Each batch of the streaming will need the same structure, it can't be dynamic between dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

Only way you can do this **`without collecting to driver`** node(*first,take,collect etc*), is if you the know the **`columns you need`** or the **`max size of each array column.`** Here I assumed both columns had a **`max size of 3`**, with columns required **`0,1,2.`**

*Also in streaming you cant have different schema(columns) between dataframes.*

```
cols=['0','1','2']

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("struct1", F.struct(*[F.struct((F.col("sents")[int(x)]).alias('sents[{}]'.format(x))) for x in cols]))\
  .withColumn("struct2", F.struct(*[F.struct((F.col("metadata")[int(x)]).alias('metadata[{}]'.format(x))) for x in cols]))\
  .select(*["struct1.{}.*".format(x) for x in ['col{}'.format((int(x)+1)) for x in cols]],
          *["struct2.{}.*".format(x) for x in ['col{}'.format((int(x)+1)) for x in cols]]).show()

#+--------+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
#|sents[0]|sents[1]|sents[2]|metadata[0]|metadata[1]|metadata[2]|
#+--------+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
#|       1|      -1|       0|     0.4991|     0.5378|        0.0|
#|      -1|    null|    null|     0.6281|       null|       null|
#|      -1|    null|    null|      0.463|       null|       null|
#+--------+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```